# how to bake in a record count in a sql query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query that looks like this:

```
select id, extension, count(distinct(id)) from publicids group by id,extension;
```

This is what the results looks like:

```
     id      |        extension        | count 
-------------+-------------------------+-------
 18459154909 | 12333                   |     1
 18459154909 | 9891114                 |     1
 18459154919 | 43244                   |     1
 18459154919 | 8776232                 |     1
 18766145025 | 12311                   |     1
 18766145025 | 1122111                 |     1
 18766145201 | 12422                   |     1
 18766145201 | 14141                   |     1
```

But what I really want is for the results to look like this:

```
   id      |        extension        | count 
-------------+-------------------------+-------
 18459154909 | 12333                   |     2
 18459154909 | 9891114                 |     2
 18459154919 | 43244                   |     2
 18459154919 | 8776232                 |     2
 18766145025 | 12311                   |     2
 18766145025 | 1122111                 |     2
 18766145201 | 12422                   |     2
 18766145201 | 14141                   |     2
```

I'm trying to get the count field to show the total number of records that have the same id.

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: `distinct` is ***NOT***  a function

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to count distincts extentions, not ids.

Run this query:

```
select id
     , extension
     (select count(*) from publicids p1 where p.id = p1.id ) distinct_id_count
  from publicids p
  group by id,extension;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more or less the same as Pastor's answer. Depending on what the optimizer does it might be faster with higher record count source tables.

```
select p.id, p.extension, p2.id_count
from publicids p

inner join (
  select id, count(*) as id_count 
  from publicids group by id
) as p2 on p.id = p2.id
```